# Android sometimes getSerializableExtra returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, crashlytics

I publish an app that works normally but sometimes (very rarely) getSerializableExtra method return null (detected with Crashlytics). 
Does anyone know why?

Exemple Launch intent:

```
    if (obj != null) {        
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()/this, ActivityToLaunch.class);
        intent.putExtra(ActivityToLaunch.ARGS, obj);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Getting data in onCreate methode :

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra(ARGS);
```

My obj is a custom serializable class, for exemple :

```
public class Program implements Serializable, Comparable<Program> {    

private long idProgram;
private String name;

public long getIdProgram() {
    return idProgram;
}

public void setIdProgram(long idProgram) {
    this.idProgram = idProgram;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Program another) {
    return getName().compareTo(another.getName());
}}
```

Comment: Perhaps there are corner cases where either you are not adding the extra or `obj` is `null`. You could consider adding a `static` method to `ActivityToLaunch` that accepts the `obj` parameter and a `Context` as input and can perform validation on `obj`. Then, migrate everything over to use that `static` method. Also, what is the data type of `obj`? If it is some custom class... I try to avoid that. [This blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html) talks about `Parcelable`, but `Serializable` will have similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's impossible that my object is null because I check before creating my intent :/ My obj is a custom serializable class.

Comment: Show your custom object class code

Comment: @FetalError  I add a exemple but my problem occurs with several different class

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?